# Using "filter" to add elements on a page to an array by name instead of id

Tags: javascript, ajax, mootools

Thanks to some help from @Dimitar Christoff I was able to get some Ajax issues sussed out. Namely grabbing only specific elements by ID from a loaded page. In the example below these predetermined elements are added to a `panels` array and are then accessed by calling `panel[0]`, `panel[1]`, etc. Problem is these elements may not always be added to the array in the same order, so in one case `panel[0]` may actually be `<div id="panel_2"></div>` and in other cases it may be `<div id="panel_1"></div>`.

How can change the return to add the element by name so I can instead call `panel['panel_0']`?

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/brandondurham/SPUFe/

Comment: What Javascript toolkit are you using?  (For example, what is the value of $$ in your example code?)

Comment: Sorry. Thought the tag would suffice. Using Mootools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't know the Javascript toolkit you are working with, but I'm guessing that if it has a filter function it probably also has a reduce function.  Here's an example of how you might reduce an array to an object (which can then be used as requested):

```
var panelsMap = panels.reduce(function (map, el, index, array) {
  map[el.get("id")] = el;
  return map;
}, {});
```

Alternatively, you could do the work inside of the original loop.  In this case it doesn't  make any sense to use "filter", but you could probably replace that with forEach or something similar.  Here's an example (which continues to use filter):

```
onComplete: function() {
    var weLike = ["panel_1", "panel_2", "panel_3"];
    var panels = {};
    $$(this.response.elements).filter(function(el) {
        if ($(el) && el.get && weLike.contains(el.get("id"))) {
          panels[el.get("id")] = el;
        }
        return false;
    });

    alert(panels);
}
```

Comment: With option #2 shouldn't it be `var panels = [];`? Also, after running the filter if I alert `panels.length` it alerts 0.

Comment: No, you want an object (var panels = {}), not an array (var panels = []).  You said that you want to be able to use the expression panels['panel_0'], right?  That's how you would use an object.  If it were an array, you'd use nonnegative integer subscripts like panels[0].  Also, if you want to know the number of mappings, assuming you're in an ECMAScript 5 environment, you could use the expression Object.keys(panels).length